# make text crawl right to left in a range of cells in a single row

Tags: vba, excel

This is a tricky one!

I want to make a word or short phrase crawl across a range of 30 cells in a single row from right to left repeating continuous in a loop, and slow enough to read as it moves.

Can anyone help with the code please!

I have managed to do this one character at a time, but I want to make the whole word crawl, one character per cell.

This is so far the hardest vba challenge I have faced!

Thanks in advance.

Here is code snippet of my basic version:

```
For CounterTxt = 1 To textLngt

    chaseEnd = chaseEnd + 1

    For CounterChase = chaseBeg To chaseEnd - 1 Step -1

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, CounterChase + 1).Value = "" ' deleats previous chase position while running.
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, CounterChase).Value = Mid(MyText, CounterTxt, 1)

        Sleep 20

    Next CounterChase

Next CounterTxt
```

Comment: Please include the code you are currently using for the crawling letter (or a working minimalist version of the code), so we don't have to start from scratch to help....

Comment: Please show how far you have gotten, by pasting your current code in the original post

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)**.  Please share your "one char at a time" code and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Essentially `Cell = Right(cell, 1) & Mid(cell, 2, len(cell)-1)` will do the cell “offset”

Comment: Then you’ll (I guess, I’m sure there’s a better method) use something like `Application.OnTime` to call the function over and over. But to be clear, I’d be hesitant about opening yourself a loop with no clear ending

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub March()
    Dim str As String
    str = "Hello World"

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")

    rng.ClearContents

    Dim secondstr As String
    secondstr = str & Application.Rept(" ", rng.Cells.Count)

    Dim vlue As String
    vlue = StrConv(secondstr, vbUnicode)

    Dim substr() As String
    substr = Split(Left(vlue, Len(vlue) - 1), vbNullChar)


    Dim i As Long
    For i = rng.Cells.Count + rng.Column - 1 To rng.Column Step -1
        If i = rng.Column Then
            Dim j As Long
            For j = 0 To Len(str)
                Dim k As Long
                For k = 1 To Len(str) + 1
                    rng.Cells(1, k) = substr(j + k - 1)
                Next k
                Application.Wait Now() + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60#)
            Next j

        Else
            rng.Cells(1, i).Resize(, Application.Min(Len(secondstr), rng.Cells.Count - i + 1)) = substr
            Application.Wait Now() + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60#)
        End If

    Next i

    March


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I will try to work out your code, but I was hoping for some more common everyday codding.

Comment: Just to clarify the problem; the word or phrase is dynamic and is stored in a string variable.

Comment: Then you would refer to that variable in place of `str` this is just showing you how to do it.

Comment: And as to common everyday, this is common everyday to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I should be able to work with your code.

Answer (score 2):

exploiting @ScottCraner 's `StrConv(secondstr, vbUnicode)` feature, and assuming no harm on deleting cells in relevant row, here's another approach:

```
Sub CrawlItLeftwards(myText As String, chaseRow As Long, chaseBeg As Long)
    Dim chaseCol As Long, textLngt As Long

    textLngt = Len(myText)
    Cells(chaseRow, chaseBeg).Resize(, textLngt).Value = Split(StrConv(myText, vbUnicode), Chr(0)) 'write the text once
    For chaseCol = 1 To chaseBeg + textLngt - 1 ' delete the first column cell to make it crawl leftwards
        Cells(chaseRow, 1).Delete xlToLeft
        Application.Wait Now() + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60#)
    Next
End Sub
```

which you may call as follows:

```
CrawlItLeftwards "Hello", 7, 10 ' make the string "Hello" crawl in row 7 from column 10 leftwards
```

---

of course you may expand the parameters list to, for instance, enclose wanted sheet :

```
Sub CrawlItLeftwards (myText As String, sht As Worksheet, chaseRow As Long, chaseBeg As Long)
    Dim chaseCol As Long, textLngt As Long

    textLngt = Len(myText)
    sht.Activate ' make sure you're looking at/acting in the relevant sheet
    Cells(chaseRow, chaseBeg).Resize(, textLngt).Value = Split(StrConv(myText, vbUnicode), Chr(0)) 'write the text once
    For chaseCol = 1 To chaseBeg + textLngt - 1 ' delete the first column cell to make it crawl leftwards
        Cells(chaseRow, 1).Delete xlToLeft
        Application.Wait Now() + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60#)
    Next
End Sub
```

and hence calling it like:

```
CrawlItLeftwards "Hello", Worksheets("Sheet1"), 7, 10 ' make the string "Hello" crawl in sheets "Sheet1" row 7 from column 10 leftwards
```

Comment: Thanks DisplayName, I will play around with this to see what it gives.

Comment: @FranckLouis, any feedback?